# ThreadPool and delegate action - WaitHandle.WaitAll()

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, threadpool

I want to start a simple delegate action couple times in `ThreadPool`. The problem is I need to wait for all the actions to finish. How to handle that?

```
Action<int> someAction = i => { /* do something */ }
foreach (var yIndex in yRange)
{
    foreach (var xIndex in xRange)
    {
        // ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(??? someAction(yIndex)) - how to start someAction(int) in a thread pool
    }

    WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents); // how to wait for to finish?
}
```

I know I could use a new class and create a `ManualResetEvent` callback. But the problem is `someAction(int)` uses many methods that are implemented in the main class...

Comment: *But the problem is someAction(int) uses many methods that are implemented in the main class* - could you elaborate on that? Do you mean you need to make calls to the UI thread from your tasks executing on pool threads (in which case you may not use `WaitHandle.WaitAll` to avoid blocking)?

Comment: No. I have a working class (not UI thread) that should run some actions async. Now I want want to wait for `x-foreach` loop to finish, because as you can see `someAction` depends on `yIndex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Task Parallel Library:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

foreach(var yIndex in yRange)
  foreach(var xIndex in xRange)
    actions.Add(() => someAction(yIndex));

Parallel.Invoke(actions.ToArray());
```

[Parallel.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) returns when all tasks are done and runs them in parallel when possible (just like a thread pool).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Does `Parallel.Invoke` uses all the machine resources (highest priority)? Because it's an app that should work for around 4-5 days and do some work. It should take as much resources as it can:)

Comment: One detail: Parallel Task is available only from version 4.0 of the .NET Framework.

Comment: It runs with the same task scheduler as the application, so raising the priority of the application will elevate your threads as well. By default it takes as much resources as it can get. At my machine (for example) a parallel application with this structure occupies 100% on all cores (as reported by the windows task scheduler). You can implement your own scheduler if you want to modify the behaviour, see this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx

Comment: @Nickon Also have a look at [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) - it might also be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Take [Matten's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333333/158779) and use the TPL mechanisms. There are many different valid ways of doing this with the TPL.

If you are curious how this is done using the old-school methods then continue reading. The general pattern is to use a single signaling mechanism. Creating a `WaitHandle` for each operation is not scalable at all. In fact the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method will only accept 64 handles anyway.

```
foreach (var yIndex in yRange)
{
    var yclosure = yIndex;
    var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
    foreach (var xIndex in xRange)
    {
        var xclosure = xIndex;
        finished.AddCount();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
          (state) =>
          {
            try
            {
              DoSomething(yclosure, xclosure);
            }
            finally
            {
              finished.Signal();
            }
          }, null);
    }
    finished.Signal();
    finished.Wait();
}
```

The pattern above uses `CountdownEvent` as the signaling mechanism. You could also use an `int` counter and the `Interlocked` methods as well. There are two common mistakes people make when using this pattern.

1. You should treat the main thread as if it were parallel task just like the others. That means we need to initialize the signal with 1 count (to represent the main thread). And then we signal that the main thread is done queueing the tasks via `Signal` at the end of the loop. If you fail to follow this advice then you open up the possibility for a *very* subtle race condition that could occur if one task finishes before the next is queued up.<sup>1</sup>
2. You must create separate variables for the closure of any loop variables that you want 
   to use in the lambda expression or anonymous delegate. Remember, closures capture the *variable* and not the *value* so the task may not be working with the value you think it is if you do not use a special capturing variable.

---

<sup>1</sup>*In this particular case `AddCount` would actually throw an exception if the event is already signaled.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a Semaphore object to accomplish your goal. Try this:

```
int numActions = xRange.Count * yRange.Count; // Set the total number of actions
Semaphore resCount = new Semaphore(0, numActions);
Action<int> someAction = i => { try {/* do something */} finally {resCount.Release(1);} }
// ... the big loop adding actions
resCount.WaitOne();
```

The code is not exact, but the idea should work.

Comment: And then - busy wait until all are completed?